# UIPickerView multi selection on ios7

Tags: forms, ios7

I need a picker view witch i can select multi values, like the "select input" in HTML :

[image: Select input rendered in Safari]

In ios6, i did it with a custom view created in the UIPickerViewDelegate (pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:) and a UIButton in each row, but since ios7, the custom view don't received the touch event.

Is it possible to do it in ios7 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DrDisc has confirmed that it is not possible to handle a touch event directly from a row view since ios7.

But it is possible to :

1. add a Tap Gesture to the UIPickerView
2. retrive the selected view
3. call a method to check / uncheck the row

   ```
   int row = [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
   UIView *rowView = [self.pickerView viewForRow:row forComponent:0];
   if([rowView isKindOfClass:[YouCustomView class]])
   {
       [(YouCustomView*)rowView toggleCheck];
       [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
   }
   ```

I think it is more natural than a button to check/uncheck, but we lost the ability to select an other row with a tap on it.

Comment: Add a tap gesture does not work on iOS9. Use the didSelectRow delegate method as DrDisc mentioned works.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this is not possible. One option is to utilize UIPickerView's delegate method:

`- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`

You could store the selection in an array and change the text passed through from the data source to some sort of selection text ("x Selection 1").

Alternatively, you could have a 'select item' button that would add the currently displayed value to the selected array.

When the user clicks a button you can then look through the selected array for those that were selected.

These may not be the best methods, they're just my initial thoughts on it.